# How to avoid prompt to save buffer when running emacs batch

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm running

```
/usr/bin/emacs -l ~/.emacs -eval '(org-icalendar-export-agenda-files)' --batch
```

in a cron job.

Orgmode adds the `uuid` to the properties of new todo items in the agenda files, but then prompts to save the agenda files (only when run from the command line in batch mode).

```
Save file /home/user/gtd/work.org? (y or n)
```

My cludgy work around is to `echo y | /usr/bin/emacs...`.  But since there are actually 3 agenda files that are potentially modified, this is not a good solution.  There must be some variable to set or something that will cause `org-icalendar-export-agenda-files` to just save the files it modifies.

Comment: The function `org-icalendar-export-agenda-files` has an optional argument labelled `async`.  Does setting it to true with `(org-icalendar-export-agenda-files t)` help?

Comment: Was hoping so but I get an error:  
Initializing asynchronous export process

Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
bkelly@y2 ~ $
Tried setting it to a 0,1,nil,string.  It only accepts nil

Comment: I've  had `/usr/bin/emacsclient -e "(progn (org-save-all-org-buffers) (org-icalendar-export-agenda-files t))"`` working in a cron job for a while now.

Comment: And if you can't get it to work, replace your `echo y` with the `yes` command which just infinity echos "yes"

Comment: Can you set `buffer-save-without-query` for the relevant instances?  Otherwise, the contents of your `.emacs` are going to be relevant.  One approach would be to make a copy, load that instead and cut it down to the minimum relevant for your export.

Comment: That looked promising but still didn't work!  All i have in stripped down .emacs is  require 'org and a few org-icalendar settings for time zone and todos etc.   This is emacs 24.4.1 on Fedora 22.  Have I hit a bug or emacs default configuration issue? Let me see if I can get some alternate emacs going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `defadvice` is not a good practice in general<sup>1</sup> but, if you want to fix this and can't wait your fix to get included in the next emacs release, try this:

```
(defadvice org-icalendar-create-uid (after org-icalendar-create-uid-after activate)
  (save-buffer))
```

This advices `org-icalendar-create-uid` so that when a new UID is created, the current buffer gets saved<sup>2</sup>. You need to be really careful advising functions. I would recommend to create a `export-icalendar.el` script similar to this:

```
;; initialize org-mode
(require 'org)

;; pick your agenda files
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org"))

;; store UIDs in properties drawer
(setq org-icalendar-store-UID t)

;; optional configuration
(setq org-icalendar-use-scheduled '(event-if-todo event-if-not-todo))
(setq org-agenda-default-appointment-duration 50)

;; avoid interactive prompts if UIDs are created
(defadvice org-icalendar-create-uid (after org-icalendar-create-uid-after activate)
  (save-buffer))

(org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files)
```

To run it, do it like this<sup>3</sup>:

```
emacs --batch -l export-icalendar.el
```

<sub>1: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions</sub>

<sub>2: `org-icalendar-create-uid` is called inside `with-current-buffer`, see `ox-icalendar.el` for details.</sub>

<sub>3: Never run `org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files` through `eval` using `emacsclient`, it causes problems if you were already visiting agenda files.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Would you be helped by 
the function save-some-buffers 
in emacs?
Like in

```
/usr/bin/emacs -l ~/.emacs -eval '(progn (org-icalendar-export-agenda-files) (save-some-buffers t))' --batch
```

Yes, it can been seen as a kludge.

Comment: aarg.  It still prompts to save the file just with a no files need saving message *after* the export. Wrote /home/bkelly/gtd/work.ics
Save file /home/.../gtd/personal.org? (y or n) y
Saving file /home/.../gtd/personal.org...
Wrote /home/.../gtd/personal.org

(No files need saving)